# Flutter - InheritedWidget - dispose

Tags: flutter

I was wondering if anybody knew a way to know when an InheritedWidget was disposed?

The reason of this question is that I am doing some experiments and I am using an InheritedWidget as a provider of a BLoC.
This BLoC is initialized at the InheritedWidget level, and uses a StreamController.

As it is more than recommended to close a StreamController, I am trying to find a solution.

Here is a piece of code (silly code just for experiments) to illustrate the question:

```
///
/// ApplicationProvider
/// 
/// A provider of ApplicationBloc
/// 
class ApplicationProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  //
  // Initialization of the BLoC
  //
  final ApplicationBloc bloc = new ApplicationBloc();

  ApplicationProvider({Key key, Widget child}) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(_) => true;

  static ApplicationBloc of(BuildContext context, [bool redraw = true]) {
    return redraw ? (context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(ApplicationProvider) as ApplicationProvider).bloc
                  : (context.ancestorWidgetOfExactType(ApplicationProvider) as ApplicationProvider).bloc;
  }
}

//
// The BLoC
//   
class ApplicationBloc {

  int _counter;
  StreamController<int> _counterController = new StreamController<int>.broadcast();
  Sink get inCounter => _counterController;

  Stream<int> get outCounter => _counterController.stream;

  ApplicationBloc(){
    _counter = 0;
  }

  void increment(){
    _counter++;
    inCounter.add(_counter);
  }

  int get counter => _counter;

  //
  // How could I call this method ???
  //
  void dispose(){
    _counterController.close();
  }
}
```

So the main question is "**how can I call the dispose() method of my BLoC**" ?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`InheritedWidget` behaves the same way as other `Widget` do.
Their lifetime is really short: Usually not longer than one `build` call.

If you want to store data for longer, `InheritedWidget` is not what you want. You'll need a `State` for that.

Which also means that ultimately, you can use `State`'s dispose for your bloc dispose.

```
class BlocHolder extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  BlocHolder({this.child});

  @override
  _BlocHolderState createState() => _BlocHolderState();
}

class _BlocHolderState extends State<BlocHolder> {
  final _bloc = new MyBloc();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyInherited(bloc: _bloc, child: widget.child,);
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    _bloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class MyInherited extends InheritedWidget {
  final MyBloc bloc;

  MyInherited({this.bloc, Widget child}): super(child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) {
    return oldWidget != this;
  }
}


class MyBloc {
  void dispose() {

  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rémi, that is what I feared since I would have liked not to be obliged to use a StatefulWidget for this.  Don't you know if there is any plans to extend Dart so that classes support the notion of destructor :) ?

Comment: Destructor is not the problem. You shouldn't store your "BLOC" or anything similar inside `InheritedWidget` anyway. You could easily find yourself into a situation where your bloc gets an hard reset without any obvious reasons

Comment: Why do you not want to use a `StatefulWidget`? It's one of the basic building blocks of Flutter, there is nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Inherited widgets behave very much like stateless widgets, which also do not have a `dispose` method. Inherited widgets are getting rebuilt frequently, and all the values stored inside of it would be lost (and without a proper `updateShouldNotify` implementation, the dependent widget trees will also be rebuilt frequently!).

To solve this problem, you can utilize a `StatefulWidget`:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class ApplicationProvider extends StatefulWidget {
  const ApplicationProvider({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ApplicationProviderState();
}

class _ApplicationProviderState extends State<ApplicationProvider> {
  final ApplicationBloc bloc = new ApplicationBloc();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    bloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _ApplicationProvider(
      bloc: bloc,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}

class _ApplicationProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  _ApplicationProvider({
    Key key,
    this.bloc,
    Widget child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  final ApplicationBloc bloc;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(_ApplicationProvider oldWidget) {
    return bloc != oldWidget.bloc;
  }
}

class ApplicationBloc {
  ApplicationBloc of(BuildContext context) {
    final _ApplicationProvider provider = context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_ApplicationProvider);
    return provider.bloc;
  }

  int _counter;
  StreamController<int> _counterController = new StreamController<int>.broadcast();
  Sink get inCounter => _counterController;

  Stream<int> get outCounter => _counterController.stream;

  ApplicationBloc() {
    _counter = 0;
  }

  void increment() {
    _counter++;
    inCounter.add(_counter);
  }

  int get counter => _counter;

  void dispose() {
    _counterController.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced a similar issue, and I found you could implement a similar behaviour to dispose by overriding the `unmount()` method of your inheritedWidget's element like so:

#### InheritedWidget

```dart
class InheritedBeauty extends InheritedWidget {
  final int Function() createBeautyValue;

  const InheritedBeauty({
    required this.createBeautyValue,
    Key? key,
    required Widget child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  static InheritedBeauty of(BuildContext context) {
    final InheritedBeauty? result =
        context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<InheritedBeauty>();
    assert(result != null, 'No MyInheritedWidget found in context');
    return result!;
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedBeauty old) {
    return false;
  }

  @override
  InheritedBeautyElement createElement() => InheritedBeautyElement(
        this,
        beautyValue: createBeautyValue(),
      );
}
```

note that when trying to access the inheritedwidget's value, call `context.getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType()` 
 and note that this does not establish any relationship between the target and in the way that `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType` does.

#### InheritedElement

`where the magic happens`

```dart
class InheritedBeautyElement extends InheritedElement {
  int? _beautyValue;

  int? get beautyValue => _beautyValue;

  InheritedBeautyElement(
    super.widget, {
    required int? beautyValue,
  }) : _beautyValue = beautyValue;

  /// this is the code you're looking for
  @override
  void unmount() {
  /// dispose your value here, in my case I am setting [_beautyValue] to null
    _beautyValue = null;
    super.unmount();
  }
}
```