# Flutter- Understanding the lifecycle of Provider, Bloc and when to dispose the stream

Tags: flutter, bloc, inherited-widget, flutter-provider

Need to understand when we should Bloc pattern and life cycle of Bloc (how to release objects holding memory)

I have a screen where I am fetching the data from the server and data will be used for a single screen only. I am using Bloc pattern to show the data.

When using the Bloc pattern, I have a screen where I am using StatelessWidget. I am trying to dispose of the stream on 'WillPopScope'. Once disposed of, the stream cannot be used anymore. Because visiting the same screen result in a crash as I have wrapped my MaterialApp with the Bloc.

1. created a stream

```
    final _leaderBoardList = StreamController<List<dynamic>>.broadcast();
```

2. disposing stream

```
    dispose() {
      print('_leaderBoardList disposed');
      _leaderBoardList.close();
    }
```

3. wrapping Material App within the provider:

```
    LeaderBoardProvider(
        child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Table View Fetch',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
        ),
        home: HomeScreen(),
      ),
      );
```

4. Statelesswidget 'WillPopScope', I have commented dispose of code as currently bloc is created once as I understood:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print(' ListView fetch Build called');
    final bloc = LeaderBoardProvider.of(context);
    bloc.fetchLeaderBoards();
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        //bloc.dispose();
        return true;
      },
      child: bodyStack(context, bloc),
    );
  }
```

**The first Question**, Suppose I create a broadcast stream and remove dispose of code in 'WillPopScope', then everything works as expected but I think, this way, my Bloc hold a memory for app lifetime.

**Second Question**, How to handle such cases in which data is used within a screen. Is Bloc pattern recommended for this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not dispose BLoC within `WillPopScope`.

It is the job of your "Provider" to handle the disposal of your BLoC: It should close streams when the provider widget is removed from the tree.

This is achieved by your Provider being a `StatefulWidget` (with an internal private `InheritedWidget` to expose the BLoC) and overriding `dispose` method.

See [Flutter: How to correctly use an Inherited Widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491860/flutter-how-to-correctly-use-an-inherited-widget/49492495#49492495) for an example (it's not related to BLoC and doesn't have a `dispose`, but the idea is similar).

Comment: Understood, you are recommending this approach which you have answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51690319/2644723.

Comment: Also in the same link, you have mentioned
" InheritedWidget behaves the same way as other Widgets do. Their lifetime is really short: Usually not longer than one build call.

If you want to store data for longer, InheritedWidget is not what you want. You'll need a State for that." Just to clarify, here you mean state using GlobalKey as key?

Comment: No. Using an actual State subclass

Comment: `_ViewControllerState createState() => _ViewControllerState();`
`}`

`class _ViewControllerState extends State<ViewController> {`
 ` // the widget's persistent state goes here`
`  @override`
  `Widget build(BuildContext context) {`
    `// return a widget based on the persistent state`
 ` }`
`}`


Do you mean this by State subclass? Can you please quote an example.