# How to dispose stream on closing flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I have a stream in my flutter app that is continuosly detecting the network change .It is defined in the main function.

```
Map _source = {ConnectivityResult.none: false};
CurrentConnectivity _connectivity = CurrentConnectivity.instance;
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await init();
  HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();


  _connectivity.initialise();
  _connectivity.myStream.listen((source) {
    _source=source;
  }, onError: (err) {
    print(err);
  }, cancelOnError: false);

  runApp(AppWidget());
  _connectivity.disposeStream();
}
```

But when i navigate i get this exception

**EXCEPTION**

```
E/flutter ( 6822): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close
E/flutter ( 6822): #0      _BroadcastStreamController.add (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:251:24)
E/flutter ( 6822): #1      _StreamSinkWrapper.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:873:13)
E/flutter ( 6822): #2      CurrentConnectivity._checkStatus (package:iris_flutter/core/network/current_connectivity.dart:61:21)
E/flutter ( 6822): #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
E/flutter ( 6822): #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
E/flutter ( 6822): #5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:141:18)
E/flutter ( 6822): #6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:682:45)
E/flutter ( 6822): #7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:711:32)
E/flutter ( 6822): #8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
E/flutter ( 6822): #9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:36:15)
E/flutter ( 6822): #10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:298:13)
E/flutter ( 6822): #11     SendOfflineRequests.call (package:iris_flutter/features/faculty/attendance/domain/usecases/offline_requests/send_offline_requests.dart)
E/flutter ( 6822): #12     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
E/flutter ( 6822): #13     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
E/flutter ( 6822): #14     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:141:18)
E/flutter ( 6822): #15     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:682:45)
E/flutter ( 6822): #16     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:711:32)
E/flutter ( 6822): #17     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
E/flutter ( 6822): #18     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:36:15)
E/flutter ( 6822): #19     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:298:13)
E/flutter ( 6822): #20     OfflineClassesRepositoryImpl.sendOfflineRequests (package:iris_flutter/features/faculty/attendance/data/repositories/offline_requests_repository_impl.dart)
E/flutter ( 6822): #21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
E/flutter ( 6822): #22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
E/flutter ( 6822): #23     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:141:18)
E/flutter ( 6822): #24     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:682:45)
E/flutter ( 6822): #25     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:711:32)
E/flutter ( 6822): #26     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
E/flutter ( 6822): #27     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:36:15)
E/flutter ( 6822): #28     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:298:13)
E/flutter ( 6822): #29     StudentDetailsFacultyLocalDataSourceImpl.deleteAllMarkedRecords (package:iris_flutter/features/faculty/attendance/data/datasources/students/student_details_faculty_local_data_source.dart)
E/flutter ( 6822): #30     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
E/flutter ( 6822): #31     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
E/flutter ( 6822): #32     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:141:18)
E/flutter ( 6822): #33     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:682:45)
E/flutter ( 6822): #34     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:711:32)
E/flutter ( 6822): #35     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
E/flutter ( 6822): #36     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:36:15)
E/flutter ( 6822): #37     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:298:13)
E/flutter ( 6822): #38     LocalStorage.deleteAllStoredMarkings (package:iris_flutter/core/util/local_storage.dart)
E/flutter ( 6822): #39     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
E/flutter ( 6822): #40     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
E/flutter ( 6822): #41     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:141:18)
E/flutter ( 6822): #42     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:682:45)
E/flutter ( 6822): #43     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:711:32)
E/flutter ( 6822): #44     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
E/flutter ( 6822): #45     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:36:15)
E/flutter ( 6822): #46     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:298:13)
E/flutter ( 6822): #47     DeleteStatement.go.<anonymous closure> (package:moor/src/runtime/query_builder/statements/delete.dart)
E/flutter ( 6822): #48     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
E/flutter ( 6822): #49     _
I/Toast   ( 6822): Show toast from OpPackageName:com.example.iris_flutter, PackageName:com.example.iris_flutter
```

It works if i do not dispose the stream but i have heard that it is not a good practice to leave the stream open.
Is there a better way to close the stream or is closing the stream necessary.

EDIT1
For some answers that say that i need to use WidgetsBindingObserver i want to point out that i need to initialise the stream in main ,else the connectivity change is detected multiple times if i initialise it in a stateful/stateless widget, which breaks some logic in the code i have written.

```
class LifeCycle extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LifeCycleState createState() => _LifeCycleState();
}
class _LifeCycleState extends State<LifeCycle> with WidgetsBindingObserver {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }
  
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    print(state);
    if(state==AppLifecycleState.paused){
      GlobalClassThatInitialisesStream.disposeConnectivityStream();
    }
    if(state==AppLifecycleState.resumed){
      GlobalClassThatInitialisesStream.initialiseConnectivityStream();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppWidget();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont really get the exact question your trying to ask.

A. IF you want to close the stream on app exit
You can just call stream.cancel() when the app exits. How to detect when the app exits? For that you can make use of life cycle in flutter. Check the following youtube tutorial to learn more about it.

https://youtu.be/D_IWy2BXnEI

B.IF you are trying to fix the exception that is being raised due to navigation
Create a separate global class that checks for network connectivity. And initialize the stream inside rather than in the main function. This way when you navigate out of the main you will not see this exception.

Comment: Thank you for answering ,but the solution did not work for the reason stated in the edit part of the question.Also witting the initialising part in a global class did not help.I got the same error when i call the function (defined in the global class) to dispose the stream when i call it in when the app is in paused state

Answer (score 1):

See if you are really looking for a disposing your stream in flutter. The best way to do it using via [Flutter dispose](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html).

> To give you a jist about what inbuilt `dispose()` method does is, when your `State` is not active or finishes, it destroys your `ChangeNotifiers/Controllers/Streams etc`, and prevents your State to rebuild again, hence you don't see that error/warning

So, just make sure you have that in your `StatefulWidget()`

```
@override
void dispose() {
  // you dispose your stream here
  // or check if that works out _connectivity.dispose();
  _connectivity.disposeStream();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I would like to confirm/correct: we need to call the dispose methods on these objects manually in the overridden dispose method(?)

Comment: You just have to define it in your `State Class`, and mention your stream in the method only. Rest the state will take care, you don't need to call it somewhere, just defining it would suffice. For example, just look at the code, and see how dispose was used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51690319/5362583 **The link is just for showcase purpose.**

Comment: I'm confused, wouldn't the stream be closed anyway when the app exits and the run time is stopped?